# How to select wrapped HTML elements?

Tags: html, css, overflow, word-wrap

Suppose you have a container (div) and a bunch of nested inline-block or floated divs.
http://jsfiddle.net/D6PgE/

```
.container { width : 300px; }
.inner     { width : 100px; }

<div class="container">
    <div class="inner"> 1 </div>
    <div class="inner"> 2 </div>
    <div class="inner"> 3 </div>
    <div class="inner"> 4 </div>
    <div class="inner"> 5 </div>
    <div class="inner"> 6 </div>
    <div class="inner"> 7 </div>
    <div class="inner"> 8 </div>
    <div class="inner"> 9 </div>
</div>
```

***What is the best way to select elements that have been wrapped?***  Is it possible to select the *nth element* of a wrapped row (in the fiddle it would be the odd numbers).

*The only thing I can think of is to use JS and compare the offsetTop position of the elements; however I haven't kept up with CSS lately and know that its becoming ever more powerful, so is there a CSS solution? -thanks*

---

**Edit**
I am trying to select the nth-element of a "row". The issue is that there are no rows as this is not a table. I should also add that my example was simple because the widths may very, so there may be more or elements per line - therefore something like `nth-child` will not work

Comment: What do you mean by wrapped exactly? As in, elements that have no children?

Comment: I think he means visually wrapped to next "line".

Comment: "The only thing I can think of is to use JS and compare the height of elements;" Are you trying to make all <li> elements the same height?

Comment: @ckaufman: I am not trying to make all elements the same height.  I am trying to select the nth-element of a "row".  The issue is that there are no rows as this is not a table.  Also, my example was simple because the widths may very, so there may be more or elements per line.  So in order to determine if the element is on a new line I have to compare the how high the element is w/in the page/container (offsetTop) - ahh I should change my wording (*thanks*)

Comment: @JamWaffles: exactly as vrutberg said - visually wrapped, which used to be impossible with CSS, but I've heard CSS is much more powerful these days

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no CSS solution that will work with unknown/dynamic sizes, as selectors cannot select based on how elements are being laid out or how their styles are computed.

You will need to use JS to obtain and work with that kind of information.

Comment: This is my guess as well, but I was hopeful.

Answer (score -1):

A simple CSS3 solution would be to use the 
    `nth-child`
selector.
I've updated your fiddle with a couple of example http://jsfiddle.net/D6PgE/6/.

For further reference: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: Are you serious...Load the new answers before save your answers

Comment: This will only work when the widths of the container and inner elements are known and fixed.

Comment: @waldyr.ar: Nobody has to be forced to do that. Somebody posted a similar answer a short while after you did. That is fine. What is not fine is if someone copied and pasted your answer word for word.

Comment: @BoltClock: exactly, perhaps I was a little misleading in my question when I gave the container a width, but there was no simpler way to show the wrapping

Comment: @BoltClock: I don't see how the widths factor into the nth-child selector, could you explain please?

Comment: @MalSu: If you change the widths such that the inner elements rewrap differently, `:nth-child()` won't work as expected anymore. See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/D6PgE/7